# Grouping Worksheets with Similar Name Suffix

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggeling to figure out the best way to attack this problem. I'm looking to group worksheet tabs and color code them based on the suffix.

Eg:

Worksheet Names:

```
ToDo_XY
Done_ZY
ToDo_ZY
Done_XY
```

Should be:

```
ToDo_XY
Done_XY
ToDo_ZY
Done_ZY
```

I know that the worksheet name will end in "non alphanumeric character" in the 3rd last position then two letters and I need to group by the two letters.

I'm not sure if I should be using a collection, or a dictionary or somehow arrays.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub GroupLabSheets()

 Call GetLabListFromTextFile

 Dim ThirdLastCharStr As String, ThirdLastCharStrIsAlphaNumBool As Boolean, PossibleLabStr As String, PossibleLabStrExistsBool As Boolean
 
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  ThirdLastCharStr = Mid(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - 3, 1)
  ThirdLastCharStrIsAlphaNumBool = IsAlphaNumeric(ThirdLastCharStr)
  PossibleLabStr = Right(ws.Name, 2)
  PossibleLabStrExistsBool = mylabs.Exists(PossibleLabStr)
     If ThirdLastCharStrIsAlphaNumBool = False And PossibleLabStrExistsBool = True Then
     
      Debug.Print "Worksheet Name = " & ws.Name & " - Index = " & ws.Index
           
     End If
  Next ws
  
   
  Dim WSArr As Variant
  WSArr = Array("ToDo_XY", "Done_XY")
  'WSArr.Move Before:=Sheets(1)

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(WSArr) To UBound(WSArr)
   Debug.Print Worksheets(WSArr(i)).Name
   Worksheets(WSArr(i)).Tab.Color = WHLabTabColor
   Worksheets(WSArr(i)).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
  Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(ByVal vInput As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oRegEx                As Object
 
    If IsNull(vInput) = False Then
        Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        oRegEx.Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
        IsAlphaNumeric = oRegEx.Test(vInput)
    Else
        IsAlphaNumeric= True 'Null value returns True, modify as best suits your needs
    End If
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not oRegEx Is Nothing Then Set oRegEx = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    Debug.Print "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: IsAlphaNumeric" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub ArrangeSheets()
    
    Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, suffix, colors, col As Collection, n As Long
    
    colors = Array(vbRed, vbYellow, vbGreen, vbBlue) 'colors to be applied (may need to add more...)
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'collect and group all matched worksheets according to their suffix
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If SortIt(ws) Then
            suffix = Right(ws.Name, 2)
            If Not dict.exists(suffix) Then dict.Add suffix, New Collection
            dict(suffix).Add ws
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'now loop over the groups and move all sheets in a group
    '   after the first sheet in that group
    For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        Set col = dict.Items()(i)
        For n = 1 To col.Count
            Set ws = col(n)
            ws.Tab.Color = colors(i)
            If n > 1 Then ws.Move after:=col(n - 1)
        Next n
    Next i

End Sub

'is this worksheet a candidate for sorting?
Function SortIt(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim nm As String
    nm = UCase(ws.Name)
    If Len(nm) >= 4 Then
        SortIt = (Not Mid(nm, Len(nm) - 2, 1) Like "[A-Z0-9]") And _
                  Right(nm, 2) Like "[A-Z][A-Z]"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think I'll end up using this answer as I can read the code better, but theres some new functions your using I don't know about yet such as `New Collection` which I'll have to google. One thing I did consider, I had originally used the other answer with a separate sub for color coding tabs and the way I had it was that I hard code suffix = color. The reason being is I'd like the same suffix to have the same color each time this is run. Currently suffix color combo could change daily based on number/order of collection.

Comment: This worked great! I was able to adjust it by setting to `ActiveWorkbook` and I just removed the `Colors Array` and used `If/Then` for Specific Suffix/Color combos.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RearrangeTabs()
    Dim a() As String, i As Integer, j As Integer, buf As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim colour As Long
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
        ReDim a(1 To .Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
        i = 1
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            buf = ws.Name
            ' make sort key
            a(i, 1) = Right(buf, 2) & IIf(Left(buf, 1) = "T", "A", "Z")
            a(i, 2) = buf
            i = i + 1
        Next
        
        ' primitive bubble sort
        For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
            For j = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
                If a(i, 1) < a(j, 1) Then
                    buf = a(i, 1): a(i, 1) = a(j, 1): a(j, 1) = buf
                    buf = a(i, 2): a(i, 2) = a(j, 2): a(j, 2) = buf
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        
        colour = 3 'start ColorIndex (built-in set of colors [1..56])
        For i = UBound(a, 1) To LBound(a, 1) Step -1
            Set ws = .Worksheets(a(i, 2))
            ws.Tab.ColorIndex = colour
            ws.Move Before:=.Worksheets(1)
            ' increment ColorIndex for every odd i
            If i Mod 2 = 1 Then colour = colour Mod 56 + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble reading code, but if I understand it correctly, it sorts ALL worksheets based on last two characters? I'm unsure what `"T", "A", "Z"` refers to. I'm also struggling to know how to color code each group.

Comment: 1. The sort key looks like `XYA` or `XYZ`, where the first two letters are the suffix and the third is for prefix ordering. If the first letter is "T" ("ToDo"), add "A", otherwise ("Done") - "Z": first output "ToDo", then "Done".

Comment: 2. Initially, I did not add color to the tabs. I did it in the new version. That uses built-in set of colors [1..56], changing color after every odd tab